# Brawl Stars API; access granted to brawlers; denied to player battle logs

Tags: python

When I try to run the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/brawlers"
api_token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahJHqcxZ8-aU-A"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_token}"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.ok:
    print(response.text)
else:
    print("Failed:", response.reason, ":", response.text)
```

It responds correctly, outputting the JSON object for all the different Brawl Stars brawlers.
But when I run it to get the battle log of a specific player:

```
import requests

player_tag = "#VLQPVPY"
url = f'https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/players/{player_tag}/battlelog'
api_token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahJHqcxZ8-aU-A"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_token}"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.ok:
    print(response.text)
else:
    print("Failed:", response.reason, ":", response.text)
```

I get

> Failed: Forbidden : {"reason":"accessDenied","message":"Invalid authorization"}

I tried it with

```
https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/events/rotation
```

It worked.

I tried

```
club_id = "2RGU08QPY"
url = "https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/clubs/{club_id}/members"
```

This didn't work even if I put a # behind the 2RGU08QPY.

I'm not sure why I keep getting access denied. Am I formatting the `player_tags`'s or the `club_id`'s incorrectly?

Comment: I already found the solution a while ago but I thought I could add it here since it may help those in the future trying to use the API. The issue is as I thought with the tags. The tag needs to be URL parsed so instead of player_tag = "#VLQPVPY" it needs to be player_tag = urllib.parse.quote(tag). After you do this it should work.

Comment: Since you found an answer to the problem, you should post it as an answer. Answering your own question is OK as long as it is useful. Don´t edit an answer into your question though.

Comment: Probably not a great idea to share your access tokens in public.

Comment: Right, I'll delete it.

Comment: Also, the actual access token is much longer. I just put a modified version for reference.

Comment: Sure, just be aware that [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75963099/revisions) is visible to any site visitor. Whenever you are posting example code that uses personal access tokens, you should replace them with obvious placeholder text. Much the same as you would (hopefully) never post your email address and password on the internet -- you would use something like "my@email.com" and "mypassword". At this point, best practice would be to revoke the token and generate a new one.

Comment: Just going to mention that the token listed in the post only has 23 actual characters out of the full 570-character API key. So I think I'm fine. I'll swap it with a normal placeholder next time though.